# Updating postgres column using python dataframe

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, dataframe

I am generating dataframe (`df`) for different dates and it will have the following variables

```
date           value     rowId
2016-05-14       2.5       1
2016-05-14       3.0       2
2016-05-14       3.4       5
```

I have to update a column (`value`) in postgres table (`Table1`). This table already contains a column (`value`) of type decimal in (`Table1`) along with unique identifier (`rowId`)

```
for d in range(0,len(df)):
        QUERY=""" UPDATE "Table1" SET "value"='%s' WHERE "Table1"."rowId"='%s'
            """ % (df['value'][d], df['rowId'][d])
        cur.execute(QUERY)
```

There is no error. However, the above code is not updating the column in Postgres table. Is there any error in the code?

Comment: the only thing is can spot perhaps is that you may have to do is to make your value and row as string.    `%(str(df['value'][d]) , str(df['rowId'][d]))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, closing transaction with commit should help. I'm not sure if you are using `psycopg2`, or any other library which has a `commit()` function. If not, then a simple `cur.execute('COMMIT')` should be enough. This should be run right after the `for` loop.